# Handling Eventual Consistency fail between aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, eventual-consistency, domain-events

I am a beginner in DDD and I came across a situation that involves a rule of not modifying more than 1 aggregate in the same transaction, using Domain Events to resolve changes in other aggregates. (see Effective Aggregate Project).

The situation is as follows: The user schedules to transfer a patient to another hospital. When the transfer time comes, the user selects it in a list and clicks 'Start'. However, this action changes three aggregates:

Transfer: marked as started. ex: transfer.Start();

Patient: is marked as being transferred. ex: patient.MarkAsInTransfer();

Hospital: you must reserve a place for the patient who is now coming. ex: hospita;.ReservePlace(patient);

Thus, when transfer starts, it raise an event TransferStarted.

But, for some reason, when the transfer is already occurring, an error occurs when handling the TransferStarted event (changing the patient's status or reserving a place in destination hospital).

How to deal with this situation, since the patient is already in transfer? I need to forget and use transactional consistency, modifying three aggregates in the same transaction? Using a Domain Service to do it?

Remembering that I am following an aggregate transaction rule.

Comment: That's why most operations in message-driven systems are designed to be idempotent that is, if you attempt to transition an AR's state to the very same state it currently is in then the operation has no effect. E.g. trying to reserve a spot for the same patient when that patient already has a reservation would have no effect. Since most messaging infrastructures have at least once delivery guarantee rather than exactly once you have to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

> How to deal with this situation, since the patient is already in transfer? I need to forget and use transactional consistency, modifying three aggregates in the same transaction? Using a Domain Service to do it?

There are a couple of aspects to what's going on here.

1) From your description, you are dealing with entities out in the real world; the book of record for the real world is the real world, not your domain model.  So when you receive a "domain event" from the real world, you need to treat it appropriately.

2) *collaborative domains*, with contributions from multiple resources out in the real world, are inherently "eventually consistent".  The people over here don't know what's going on over there, and vice versa -- they can only act on the information they have locally, and report faithfully what they are doing.

What this means, in practice, is that you need to be thinking about your "aggregates" as *bookkeeping* about what's going on in the real world, and documenting actions that conflict with policy as they occur (sometimes referred to as "exception reports").

3) Often in the case of collaborative processes, the "aggregate" is the instance of the process itself, rather than the entities participating in it.

> How to deal with this situation, since the patient is already in transfer?

You invoke the contingency protocol provided to you by the domain experts.

A way to think of it is to imagine a bunch of SMS messages going around.  You get a message from the attending announcing that the transfer is starting, and the moments later you get a message from the destination hospital that it is in lockdown.

Now what?

Well, I'm not sure - it isn't my domain.  But it's probably something like sending a message to the attending to announce that the destination has been closed.

The important things to notice here are that (a) conflicting things happening in different places is a property of distributed collaborative systems, and you have to plan for it -- the race conditions are real and (b) the information you have about the state of affairs anywhere else is always stale, and subject to revision.

Take a careful read of [Data on the Outside versus Data on the Inside](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/13/data-on-the-outside-versus-data-on-the-inside/).  The real world is *outside*, all of the information you have about it is stale.  Also, review [Memories, Guesses, and Apologies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100722052618/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pathelland/archive/2007/05/15/memories-guesses-and-apologies.aspx).

Comment: Hey dude, not related but would you happen to have good articles about how to model and implement process managers/sagas with use case samples? I'm still having trouble grasping the intricaties of replacing distributed transactions with eventual consistency sometimes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://chrisrichardson.net/post/sagas/2019/08/15/developing-sagas-part-3.html

Comment: https://abdullin.com/post/ddd-evolving-business-processes-a-la-lokad/

Comment: Thanks for the resources, I'll have a look!

Comment: So, transfer is a Saga/Process Manager?

Answer (score 0):

When I face this sort of issue, the first thing I ask myself is: "are my aggregates correct, and do they have the right responsibilities"? After all, an aggregate is a transaction boundary which encapsulates the data and the business logic for a given process. If a process needs 3 aggregates, is it possible that they are, in fact, a single aggregate?

In your particular case, a Transfer sounds like an aggregate to me (as in, there must be some business rules to enforce and some data related to it), but Hospital and Patient look suspicious to me. What kind of data and business logic do they encapsulate and are in charge of? It obviously depends on the bounded context these aggregates are in, but it's something I would double-check. I assume though that they are all in the same BC.

For example, I would consider: why does a Patient need to be marked as in transfer? what kind of business rule does it enforce? If the reason is to avoid a Patient being transferred more than once, then it shouldn't be the listening an event from the Transfer (where does the transfer come from?), instead, it should be the one creating transfers (see Udi Dahan's [Don't create aggregate roots](http://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/)). So, if you want to transfer a Patient, do Patient.TransferTo(otherHospital), which will check if the conditions are met to initiate a transfer and, if they are, send a Command to create a transfer. The Patient then can listen to TransferStarted, TransferCancelled, TransferCompleted events to update its own state safely (as a new transfer won't start until the previous one is completed either successfully or not).

From this point, the Hospital Room allocation would be something between the Transfer and the Hospital and the Patient doesn't need to know anything about it.

But regarding the Hospital, I don't know at this point, because it doesn't seem right to me that a single aggregate manages the room allocations of a whole Hospital. It seems a lot of data and responsibility and also, it's not clear to me that there's the need for transactionality: why the allocation of Patient A in Room 100 has to be transactional with the allocation of Patient B in Room 210? If you imagine the full Hospital, that's a lot of rooms and patients and a lot of contingency in a single aggregate, which won't allow concurrent changes. Obviously, I don't have enough knowledge of the domain and details to make a suggestion, these are only considerations.

Comment: The patient needs to be marked as in tranfer for other operaror do not execute other operations over he. Hospital controls its rooms

Comment: OK, so my suggestion of making the Patient to lead the creation of a transfer is a better approach than making the patient react to a TransferStartedEvent, because with the event it's impossible to ensure that several transfers are not created for a single patient. Simply make the Patient decide if a transfer can be created or not.

Comment: "Hospital controls its rooms"  it's too broad IMO. A Hospital will probably do a lot of things as a whole, but it should be possible to break it down to much smaller aggregate and business processes. Especially in terms of transactionability, you most likely don't need to keep all rooms in a single transaction. You need transactionability within a single room (or bed, if rooms have multiple beds), because you don't want to assign the same bed to multiple Patients and transactionability in the Transfer, as you don't want to Transfer the same patient to multiple Hospital beds.

Comment: There is no problem in scheduling multiples transfer for the patient. Its status do not change. It only changes when the transfer is started, after hours, days... it is tru for room reservarion too

Comment: Well, what I mean is that it is a problem to schedule multiple transfers for a single patient "at the same time". The same for hospital beds, you can't have multiple patients at the same bed at the same time. That's why you need transactionability in these cases. Also, scheduling multiple hospital rooms/beds in advance reinforces my point of not having a single Hospital AR for all rooms. That'd be a very big aggregate and why can't you book room 100 for Monday at the same time that you book room 200 for Thursday? I see more of a bed or room aggregate, not hospital.

Comment: So, eventual consistency is not acceptable in this case?

Comment: Well, that's an important part of designing your aggregates: figuring out where transactionability is mandatory and where eventual consistency is acceptable. You don't want 2 patients in a single bed at the same time and you don't want a single patient being transferred to 2 hospitals at the same time. So, make sure that these things don't depend on some events arriving in a specific order. But you might not care if a patient is already in the room of the new hospital and it takes a few seconds or minutes for your Patient aggregate to be updated.

Comment: What you think about its solution using Saga/Process Manager pattern: When TransferStarted Event is Raised, the TransferSaga dispatchs MarkPatientForTransfer command, which change de patient aggregate. The patient raises an PatientMarkedForTransfer handled by Saga. Then, Saga dispatch other command, ReserveRoomForTransfer. The Room (or Hospital) is changed and raises a RoomReserved event. Again, saga handles its event and set the transfer state as 'ready to start'.

Comment: This approach is not clear to me. How are Transfers created? How do you make sure that a single patient doesn't get transferred twice at the same time? I think it's simpler if you get your aggregates to do these tasks instead of putting a saga in between trying to coordinate everything.

Comment: Transfer is created when user schedules it (new Transfer(..)). After, user starts it. Only when the transfer is started the rules should be verified (avaliable room on destination, etc.). I am using saga to coordinate because eventual consistency is used.

Comment: Ok. As I said, I don't really like this approach. If you just do new Transfer(), there is no way to enforce that multiple concurrent transfers are not started. Read my answer about not creating aggregates out of nothing. Also, the Saga seems not necessary also. You don't have to use sagas because there is some eventual consistency somewhere. You use them (mainly) to coordinate workflows and compensation actions in case you need to rollback a workflow. It doesn't seem your scenario, but I could be wrong obviously.

Comment: The transfer could be rolledback. When do new Transfer(), the transfer is not started, it is only scheduled. After days, hours, minutes, the user could start it. Schedule a transfer only requires that an patient exists and a hospital exists. If two transfer was scheduled for same patient, there is no problem, it is only a schedule.